# Remove Java substring with regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to remove characters between `/` and `#` characters, my string is the following one:

`platform:/this/is/a/path/contentToRemove#OtherContent`

The replacement which I executed was:

```
aString.replaceAll("/.*?#", "#")
```

but what I was given in return was:

```
platform:#OtherContent
```

when I wanted:

```
platform:/this/is/a/path/#OtherContent
```

How should I have done this correctly using Regex? Is there any other solution to accomplish which I want?

Thanks.

Comment: probably change `.*` to `[^/].`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you use a Greed pattern. It will eat from the first occurrence of `/` to the end pattern. You must use:

```
aString.replaceAll("(.*/).*?#", "$1#");
```

This will get everything until the last `/` and group (`$1`) and replace it with the content of group 1 and the `#`

Comment: You may slightly improve this with `.replaceFirst("(.*/)[^#]*", "$1");`

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew That's an entirely new version for an answer. You can add it and I will upvote it gladly since uses almost the same Idea as mine one.

Answer (score 1):

Use negated character class:

```
aString = aString.replaceAll("/[^/#]*#", "/#");
//=> platform:/this/is/a/path/#OtherContent
```

`[^/#]*` is a negated character class that will find 0 or more of any characters that are not `/` and `#`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EgOjrM/2)

Comment: Hi Anubhava, will this `[^/#]` consider the inverse order?

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what you mean by inverse order here?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't saw the precedent `/` before the `[^/#]` pattern, though my question is irrelevant. Thanks for the attention :)

Answer (score 0):

```
aString.replaceAll("[^/]+#", "#");
```

[Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/iMfgtE/1)

Comment: This one has lot of backtracking (check in regex debugger on regex101)

Comment: Fair enough, but if I change it now, I'll end-up with a regex like yours which has only 38 steps! tks for pointing that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work `aString.replaceAll("/[^/]*#", "#")`

The above regex matches slash `/` and any number of nonslash `[^/]` characters followed by hash `#`.

Answer (score 0):

```
aString.replaceAll("(.*/).*#(.*)", "$1#$2");
```

This will catch all the string till last / and put that string in group 1, then it will look for #, following string will be put in group 2